# Efficient way to count occurence of a certain character in string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Here is link to the problem from a contest(which has ended):   https://justpaste.it/7g5bz

I have tried this approach.

```
p = []
n = int(input())
s = input()
q = int(input())
for _ in range(q):
  p.append(int(input()))
for pth in p:
  print(s.count(s[pth-1],0,pth-1))
```

Test cases are running fine but when I submit this solution. It is showing Time Limit Exceeded.
Is there any other more optimized way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's timing out because you are calling `count()` in a loop:

I would as first step preprocess the input string: create new list containing number of how many times the character occurrs before in the string. That way the querying the count of occurrences of character at certain index will become O(1):

```
s = 'abacsddaa'

from itertools import count
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(count)
new_s = [next(d[ch]) for ch in s] # new_s is [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3]

count_occurences = lambda idx: new_s[idx-1] 


print(count_occurences(9))
print(count_occurences(3))
```

Prints:

```
3
1
```

Comment: Now it is showing memory limit exceeded. I don't know what kind of solution they want.

Comment: @AshutoshSharma I updated the answer, the `new_s` is storing now just integers. But what memory limit do you have?

Comment: @AndrejKesley That is not known sir.